# Extracting a pattern from a string?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Ok so say I have a word: `BEER`

I want to create a string like this: `- E E -`

See that all letters other than the `E` have been replaced with a `-` and a space been introduced between each character. I can do the latter pretty easily, not the former.

Also, it may be of help that the character not to be blanked out is not known. I have to make that decision based on a `Set` of characters.

So, if I have a `Set` of words: `BEER HERE HAIR`, and I want `E` not to be blanked, my output should be this: `- E E -` `-E - E` `- - - -`.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the characters in the string.

For each character, if it is in the set setOfCharactersToNotBlankOut, print the character. If it is not then print `-`.

Comment: The problem with that is that my algorithm will run in `O(n^2)` time since it's in another loop. How can I make it run faster?

Comment: So? O(n^2) for n < 100 is as fast as the blink of an eye. Will your program actually run noticably slow? Did you measure?

Comment: I have about 176k words I need to run. :(

Comment: There you go, I made it O(n) by changing the data structure used :3

Comment: Well, I'll still have to use a nested loop to iterate over each character in the string. I guess there's no faster way to do it..

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String s = "BEER HERE HAIR";
s = s.replaceAll("[^E ]", " - ");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
 - EE -  - E - E - - - -
```